# Undo discarded uncommitted changes

Tags: git, github

So I was using the github UI application and chose to discard some uncommitted changes in a file. Afterwards, I realized that I actually needed those changes. Is there any way of undoing this discard, even though the changes were never committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. If you discarded changes without committing to version control, then there's no way to recover unless it's cached in your editor.